# Insert corresponding list to the corresponding duplicated rows

Tags: python, pandas, database, duplicates, row

I created two list :

```
list_1 = [a,b,c,d]
list_2 = [1,2,3,4]
```

And I also created a Dataframe :

```
Day   Subject
Day1  
Day2
Day3
```

I then duplicated the row by using `df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(3)]` such that it loops through many times for each individual day

```
Day   Subject 
Day1
Day1
Day1
Day2
Day2
Day2
Day3
Day3
Day3
Day1
...
```

I would like to insert list_1 into the first occurrence of each 'Day1's and list_2 to 'Day2' so that the output should be like

```
Day   Subject 
Day1  a
Day1
Day1
Day2  1
Day2
Day2
Day3
Day3
Day3
Day1  a
...
```

I think of using

```
for i in range(0, df.shape[0]-1):
if df.iloc[i, 1] == 'Day1':
    df.iloc[i, 2] = list_1[0]
```

but it loops through all Day1s.
Is there any method to do this? Many thanks!

Comment: Where will b,c,d and 2,3,4 go?

Comment: they will go to the second item of day 1 and day 2, correspondingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `ne-shift` trick to find the location of the first "DayN"s in a consecutive sequence, and fill your values into those matched days.

```
# sample dataset
days = np.tile(np.array(["Day1","Day2","Day3"]).repeat(3), 2)
df = pd.DataFrame(days, columns=["Day"])

# mark the first consecutive days
df["first"] = df["Day"].ne(df["Day"].shift())
# fill in the values
df["Subject"] = None
df.loc[df["first"] & (df["Day"] == "Day1"), "Subject"] = "a"
df.loc[df["first"] & (df["Day"] == "Day2"), "Subject"] = 1
```

Output

```
df
Out[2]: 
     Day  first Subject
0   Day1   True       a
1   Day1  False    None
2   Day1  False    None
3   Day2   True       1
4   Day2  False    None
5   Day2  False    None
6   Day3   True    None
7   Day3  False    None
8   Day3  False    None
9   Day1   True       a
10  Day1  False    None
11  Day1  False    None
12  Day2   True       1
13  Day2  False    None
14  Day2  False    None
15  Day3   True    None
16  Day3  False    None
17  Day3  False    None
```